# Using python to search for strings in a file and use output to group the content of the second folder

Tags: python, pandas

I tried writing a python code that search for one/more strings in file1.txt, and then then make a change to the findall output (e.g., change cap0001 to 1). Next the code use the modfied output to group the content of file2.txt based on matches to column "capNo" in File2.txt.

File1.txt:

```
>cap00001 supr2 
x2shh qewrrw
dsfff rggfdd

>cap00002 supr5
dadamic adertsy
waeee ddccmet
```

File2.txt

```
Ref capNo qual
AM1 1   Good
AM8 1   Good
AM7 2   Poor
AM2 2   Good
AM9 2   Good
AM6 3   Poor
AM1 3   Poor
AM2 3   Good
```

Require output:

```
capNo   counts
1   2
2   3
```

The following code did not work for me:

```
import re

With open("File1.txt","r") as InFile1:
    for line in InFile1:
        match=re.findall(r'cap\d+',line)
        if len(match) > 0:
            match=match.remove(cap0000)
            With open("File2.txt","r") as InFile2:
                df=InFile2.read()
                df2=df.groupby(match)["capNo"].value_counts()
                print(df2)
```

How can I get this code working? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the `With`s to `with`
2. Call the `read` function:
   e.g.

```py
with open('File1.txt') as f:
    InFile1 = f.read()
    # Do something with InFile1
```

3. In your code `df` is a string - you can't call `groupby` on it (did you mean to convert it to a pandas DataFrame?)

Comment: Thanks @The Thonnu I meant to convert it to pandas DataFrame.